# Dynamic array of string skips the first index

Tags: arrays, string, pascal, dynamic-arrays

I am doing a program in which the user inputs the wage, name and the number of working hours per month for a certain number of employees. This piece of code is supposed to recieve `Nemp` employees and then ask for `Nemp` names. The problem is, it always skips the first name, it displays 'Employee name:' twice and doesn't allow the user to insert the first one. I don't understand why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
program test;

uses crt;

var 
i, Nemp : integer;
employee: array of string;

BEGIN

    read(Nemp);
    SetLength (employee, Nemp);

    for i:=1 to Nemp do

    Begin

        writeln ('Employee name: ');
        readln (employee[i]);

    end;

END.
```

Comment: You need to do `readln(Nemp);` instead of `read(Nemp);`

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic arrays are zero based. You should loop from zero to `Nemp-1`. Or loop from zero to `High(employee)`.

And as @Rudy and @trincot points out, to read the length of the `employee` array, use `ReadLn(Nemp)` to avoid unwanted input effects.

---

A tip:

Enable range and overflow check in the compiler when debugging. That would have detected the error at the high range.

Comment: It still displays the 'Employee name: ' message twice and doesn't allow the first one to be inserted

Comment: Use Readln to read Nemp. Using Read for text input doesn't read the end of line. This can cause weird and more or less unexpected effects when reading more input.